# Regex expression to see if the string contains the pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions and I am finding it pretty hard to do this simple task. The entire string looks like

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Can't ls: "/home/dev/customer/*.out" not found
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 0 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 0.0
debug1: Exit status 0
debug1: compress outgoing: raw data 343, compressed 184, factor 0.54
debug1: compress incoming: raw data 860, compressed 430, factor 0.50
```

I just need to check if something like `*.out/text" not found` exists in this string. It does exist in this case but I dont get the output as true

The regex I use is `.*\*\..*" not found.*` does not work. Could anyone help?

Comment: What are you using to process the text?

Comment: Hi,I am trying to do this using webmethods. i Have a code there where we just pass strign and the regex. If the pattern is present in the string, true is returned else false is returned. The code written is in java

Comment: @user1608869 check out my regex..it would work for singleline as well as multiline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works in multiline as well as singleline mode

```
(^.*?|.*?)\.(out|text).*?not found(.*?|.*?$)
```

Comment: In short, whatever be before the phrase or after the phrase should be ignored. Be it multiline string or any single string. Is this possible in regex

Comment: @user1608869 check my regex..It WORKS in `singleline` and also in `multiline` mode!

Comment: @user1608869 can the extension be other than out or text...if so remove `(out|text)`

Comment: Yes this surely works for single line.... But multiline again it fails. For single line the code returns true. But multiline it returns false.

Comment: Hi Anirudha,I never down voted you. But just wanted to thank you as the regex works very well after i removed the carriage returs fro the string

Comment: @user1608869 - this will match for example also string `this .text is not found`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a String Match

You don't really need a regular expression for this. A simple string match will work just fine, and faster too! For example:

```
$ fgrep '.out" not found' /tmp/foo
Can't ls: "/home/dev/customer/*.out" not found
```

#### If You Really Want a Regex

You can use a regular expression if you insist, but it isn't going to work any better for your use case. Still, here it is:

```
$ egrep '\.out" not found' /tmp/foo
Can't ls: "/home/dev/customer/*.out" not found
```

The trick with the regex is to make sure you match just the minimum necessary text to ensure a correct match, rather than trying to construct the whole line with regex tokens. Simple is better in cases like this.

Comment: Hi I am not using unix. I am using an integration tool webmethodswhere we have a utiliy where i just need to pass the strign and the regex. If valid it returns true or else false

Comment: @user1608869 If you want a tool-specific answer, you need to update your question. On the other hand, the *answer* for what the correct regex needs to be to match your specific sample is unlikely to change, regardless of the tool.

Comment: The trouble you had might have been due to mIsplaced quoting. `egrep '\*\..*" not found'` should have worked fine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But '\.out" not found' /tmp/foo does not work when i pass it as the regex input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader (new java.io.InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String input = "";
    String s;
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null && s.length() != 0) input += s;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*\\.(?:out|text)\\\"\\s+not\\sfound");
    Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find())
      System.out.println("Match found");
  }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/7A7Gn).

Comment: Hi the regex does not work for string this .text is not found.

Comment: @user1608869 - Didn't you want asterisk in pattern? >> `*.text` - please clarify, as your question is then not clear enough. If not, then just remove `\\*` from the beginning of the `compile("` pattern.